# Does a matrix of rank $r$ always contain an invertible submatrix of size $r\times r$?

Tags: matrix-rank

If a matrix $A$ (it doesn't need to be a square matrix) has rank $r$, is it always possible to choose $r$ rows and $r$ columns in $A$ such that the matrix $B$ formed by removing the rows and columns that are not selected also has rank $r$, i.e., $B$ is invertible? If so, how can this be proven?

Comment: What have you tried? As a guess, I'd suggest picking $r$ linearly independent columns, and $r$ linearly independent rows, and then combine them into an $r \times r$ matrix by deleting the rows and columns not picked.

Comment: @RichardJensen I also realized that! So I answered my own question.

Comment: For the columns you will use the pivot columns in Gauss Jordan elimination.  But I don't recall any snappy argument why this is true.  And it's usually called "rank" I think.

Comment: @JakeMirra Thanks. I proved the conjecture in my answer, and I have changed "rang" to "rank."

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ has rank $r$ it has at least $r$ rows. If it has more than $r$ rows, some of the rows can be formed by combining the other rows linearly, and can therefore be removed to form a matrix $A^-$ with only $r$ rows but also with the rank $r$. The same goes for the columns, so if $A^-$ has more than $r$ columns, some of them can be removed to form an $r$-by-$r$ matrix $B$, also of rank $r$.

Comment: It is not clear, after you remove some of the rows, that the columns are still rank r.

Comment: @JakeMirra From the definition of matrix rank, i.e., the dimension of the vector space generated (or spanned) by its columns, or [equivalently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_=_row_rank), the dimension of the vector space generated by its rows, it should be pretty straightforward. What is it that is unclear?